# A closed set is convex only when $(x+y)/2$ is in the set for all $x,y$

Tags: convex-analysis

How can one prove that:

> Given that $A$  is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $A$ is convex  $\iff \frac{1}{2 }(x+y) \in A$,  $\forall x,y \in A.$

I know $\frac{1}{2}(x+y)$ is a extreme point, but I 'm not sure how to link it with the property of closed set.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, if $x \ne y$ then $(x+y)/2$ is **not** an extreme point.

Comment: thank you a lot!! I just started to learn this~~~ Can you give me some clue about how to prove the above question

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $x, y \in A$ and $0 \le t \le 1$, approximate $t x + (1-t) y$ by
$s x + (1-s) y$ where $s$ is a rational number with denominator a power of $2$.

Comment: oh, I see. I guess was thinking in a wrong way. Thanks!!